# @property (weak, nonatomic) or @property (nonatomic, weak)? Which one closest to Apple guidelines?

Tags: objective-c

If I look at UIViewController.h, I can see **atomicity before retainability**:

```
@property(nullable, nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSBundle *nibBundle;
```

As if I drag an drop an element from a .xib to a counterpart file, it generates **retainability before atomicity**:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
```

Source: Xcode 7 beta 5.

Which one is recommended or following Apple guidelines more closely?

Comment: The order is irrelevant. Use whatever order you wish.

Comment: I do know it is irrelevant. The question is about consistency and Apple recommendation.

Comment: Make it so it's just consistent in one file.

Answer (score 3):

> Which one is recommended or following Apple guidelines more closely?

The order of the attributes is unimportant, and I'm not aware of any guidelines regarding the order. Personally, I usually put the atomicity specifier at the end because it's almost always the same and the thing I care least about. A good friend puts it first because it's easiest to skip when all the `nonatomic` specifiers line up. Do what you like best.

Comment: I agree to your friend. The "unimportant" `@property` is at first place, too.

Comment: `@property` is the _most_ significant part of the line, @AminNegm-Awad; it tells you how to interpret everything else.

Comment: Of course, as `@interface` is the *most* significant part of a class declaration? I'm not a compiler, I'm a source code reader. So as I read `@interface` with my limbic system, I read `@property` with my limbic system. My attention is focussed on what follows.

Answer (score -1):

Edit to the comments:

I tried it with:

```
NSPredicate *propertyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind = %d", CXCursor_ObjCPropertyDecl];
NSMutableDictionary *properties = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[protocol visitChildrenMatchingPredicate:propertyPredicate withBlock:
^(CLNGEntity *property, CLNGEntity *parent)
{
    CXCursor cursor = property.cxCursor;
    CXType type = clang_getCursorType(cursor);
    CXString spelling = clang_getTypeSpelling(type);
    const char *cSpelling = clang_getCString(spelling);
    NSLog(@"Property type %s", cSpelling);
    return CXChildVisit_Continue;
}];
```

(Don't care about the `CLNG…` types, they are simple Objective-C wrappers around the corresponding `CX…` types. The only additional capability used here is the possibility to visit blocks matching an `NSPredicate` instance.)

However, with this code I only get the spelling of the *type* of the property, i. e. …:

```
2015-09-16 10:18:33.689 obcl_cloudInterfaceExporter[1544:507] Property type NSString *
```

… but not the complete property declaration. But I would bet that there was a function to print (dump) the whole cursor. But I cannot find it now. Sorry. (Maybe it was in the C++ API only, but later I decided to switch to the C API.)

However, since you are working on clang, you will have better chances to find it, if I do not remember that completely wrong.

Comment: When I build a compiler with clang, it let me print out the AST as source code, IIRC. So simply take the order of this output.

Comment: Nice, Amin. As I do not know how to get the AST or print it as source code,  could you tell us the given order?

Comment: Unfortunaly I did not find the print function. See edit to my answer. Maybe I remember that completely wrong, but I'm pretty sure that there has been a print function for a cursor.

Comment: Rereading your comment: You are working at improving clang format and don't know how to get the AST?